# how to serve a single page application with openshift

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, python, mod-wsgi, openshift-online-2

I'm tryng to deploy a single page app on openshift.
On openshift all the static contents have to be in wsgi/static dir, but I obviously want to serve my static index.html from the root.
Every attempts to do this with an .htaccess in wsgi/ dir doesn't seem to work.
Is it the right way to proceed? If yes, how can I debug it? Are there any openshift specific rules for htaccess?